# How to convert pok&#233;mon to accent e

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode, number-formatting, accent-sensitive

I'm receiving string from the back-end which is `pok&#233;mon` but it should be `pokémon` this is why I'm trying to find a way to convert é in the string to é but couldn't find any solution for that

- My meta tag is utf-8
- Tried normalizer

Comment: But do you _really_ need to decode it? Showing this text in HTML will display `é`

Comment: I'm using react and I'm receiving string from the back end I need to send it to a deeper child component and display it I can not directly display it in the HTML this is why I'm trying to transform before sending to child component

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the browsers built in DOM parser.  Basically set the `innerHTML` of a DOM element, and then read with the `innerText`.  Your then free to use this string inside your React control.

eg.

```js
const d = document.createElement('div');

d.innerHTML = 'pok&#233;mon';

console.log(d.innerText);
```

To make the above code more re-usable you could do ->

```js
const normalizeText = (() => {
  const d = document.createElement('div');
  return t => {
    d.innerHTML = t;
    return d.innerText;
  }
})();


console.log(normalizeText('pok&#233;mon'));
```

Comment: Yes, that works thank you!!!. Is there any simpler way like using regex

Comment: @BarışBabahan  If you was only checking for é, then you could just do a simple replace with regex, but if there lots of different ones, regex would become much more complicated, you could wrap what I've done into a simple function to make using it much easier.  I'll do another snippet showing this.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can receive from back end so it's okay to create reusable function thank you